# How to add attachments to Allure report in C#?

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

The [Allure framework](https://github.com/allure-framework) is a really beautiful framework for test reporting.
Yet it has rather bad documentation for C#.

**I want to add some things to my allure report:**

- Debug log (like all things I write to debug)
- Screenshot
- A file

How to do it? I have no idea, please help me if you know how to do it. It seems like `AllureLifecycle` class can help me but I'm not sure how to use it.

In case it matters I use Allure together with *SpecFlow* and *MS test*.

Answer (score 2):

I searched more and seems I found the Truth.

And the Truth is it's possible to add all attachments I wanted but they can be added only as a file:

```
byte[] log = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Log.GetAllLog());
AllureLifecycle.Instance.AddAttachment("DebugLog", "application/json", log, "json");
```

If you want to add a file from actually a path (location) you can do it with the same method but a different overload.

So just place this code in a "teardown\afterscenario" method or at any other place (for example at "afterstep" method) where you want to make this attachment. I use SpecFlow so if I add this to "AfterStep" hook then Allure displays those files attached to a specific step! That's amazing!)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that allure has some events that can be used.
See : https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons/blob/master/AllureCSharpCommons.Tests/IntegrationTests.cs for more information.

haven't tried it myself, but something like this should work according to the documentation.

```
  _lifecycle = Allure.DefaultLifecycle;  
  _lifecycle.Fire(new
 MakeAttachmentEvent(AllureResultsUtils.TakeScreenShot(),
                 "Screenshot",
                 "image/png"));
 _lifecycle.Fire(new MakeAttachmentEvent(File.ReadAllBytes("TestData/attachment.json"),
            "JsonAttachment",
            "application/json"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this link, I was looking for it! Hope it will help me.

Comment: it doesn't work. I was not able to add an attachment with this example (

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: actually nothing - screenshot is just not attached.

Answer (score 0):

Using this kind of code in AfterScenario method:

```
if (_scenarioContext.TestError != null)
            {
                var path = WebElementsUtils.MakeScreenshot(_driver);
                _allureLifecycle.AddAttachment(path);
            }
```

First it verifies, if Scenario passed, if not then

> WebElementsUtils.MakeScreenshot(_driver)

method makes screenshot and returns it's path. Then this path I giving to Allure. As a second parameter in the same method I can give a name of the screenshot. As a result I am getting a screenshot in AfterScenario block in Allure report.
P.S. This is only for screenshots, about logs can't tell nothing.

Answer (score 0):

With this example you can add an attachment exactly to the failed step

```
        [AfterStep(Order = 0)]
        public void RecordScreenFailure(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            if (scenarioContext.TestError != null)
            {
                Allure.Commons.AllureLifecycle allureInstance = Allure.Commons.AllureLifecycle.Instance;
                string screenshotPath = MagicMethodMakingScreenshotAndReturningPathToIt(); 
                allureInstance.UpdateTestCase(testResult => {
                    Allure.Commons.StepResult failedStepRsult = 
                        testResult.steps.First(step => step.status == Allure.Commons.Status.failed);
                    failedStepRsult.attachments.Add(new Allure.Commons.Attachment() { 
                        name = "failure screen", 
                        source = screenshotPath, 
                        type = "image/png"
                    });

                });
            }
        }
```